# android clock app seconds needle

Tags: android

I have created a clock app (not widget) in android, using the below  in xml file

```
 <AnalogClock android:id="@+id/AnalogClock" 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:dial="@drawable/widgetdial"
              android:hand_hour="@drawable/widgethour" 
              android:hand_minute="@drawable/widgetminute"/>
```

But i would also like to have a seconds needle. Can any one help me on how it is done.